# Array references in two different ways

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C arrays why is this true? a[5] == 5[a]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/in-c-arrays-why-is-this-true-a5-5a)

```
int a[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
int i=4;
printf("%d",i[a]);
```

Why do a[i] and i[a] refer to same location in the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because array subscript is *commutative* (it's an addition), the order can be swapped :

```
a[i] = *(a + i)
i[a] = *(i + a)

*(a + i) = *(i + a)
a[i] = i[a]
```